# Post anchor tag value with the ancor as submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

im trying to solve this problem a weeks ago, but still didnt solve, basicly i have a list of tags like stackoverflow tags to spcify the program language, and i have that tags associate to a user inside a form, when he clicks on a tag i want to send the value to a controller so i can use the value to get for example the threads with only that tag, my problem is that my form just has that ancor that should work as the submit and as the value send to the controller,i already tryed with the hidden field but it doesnt work because i just have the value after the user clicks and when he clicks it just submits :S

**Here is what i have**

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("listaDesafiosTag", "Desafios", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                foreach (var i in utilizador.tags)
                {
                    <ul class="tagMargin">
                        <li><a data-name="ancora" name="listaTags" class="tag" style="font-size:9px;color:@i.cor">@i.NomeTag</a></li>
                    </ul>
                }
            }
```

Comment: No need for a form....put the tag ID in data attribute and send that with ajax

Comment: can you give me a working example? im really bad with Ajax at the moment want to learn later but need to put this on work sorry :/

Comment: `$('.tag').click(function(){ $.post(url, {id: $(this).data('tag-id')}, function(response){/* do something with response*/ }); })`

Comment: what is that response in my case i want to post to the controller so he does the query etc... and i returned in my controller the new model that i did the query and the view why i need the response when i just want to send the value, the controller doesnt to the rest for me?? sorry for newbie questions

Comment: Response is whatever you need

Comment: and if i dont need anything at the moment i send the value to the controller the controller does the rest or, am i wrong?

Comment: Aren't you trying to get content for that link?

Comment: i want to send the content to the controller and the controller does the rest for me basicly

Comment: Are you wanting to load a whole new page? If so just use `href` in `<a>`

Comment: i want to return the same view but filtered with the tag value, to do that i need to send the tag value to the controller so he can query my challenges and choose the challenges that has that tag in order the problem is that i dont know how to send a ancor tag that a user clicks

Comment: So pass the id in url in the `href`...no need for javascipt that way

Comment: how? the ancor tag is also my submit

Comment: Sounds like you need to study how url's work with controllers to include data in the url. You don't need a form for this

Comment: you say if i include the own anchor tag id on the href he pass the value that i want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Get** instead  of **POST**

```
foreach (var i in utilizador.tags)
{
    <ul class="tagMargin">
        <li><a href="/controller/action/@i.NomeTag"  data-name="ancora" name="listaTags" class="tag" style="font-size:9px;color:@i.cor">@i.NomeTag</a></li>
    </ul>
 }
```